# Cannot find value in local.settings.json in in-process Azure Function

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I get back to my function after couple of months and it stopped working. **My local.settings.json has all secrets needed.** When i try to run Azure Function **locally** i receive errors like:

> Warning: Cannot find value named 'CosmosDbConection' in local.settings.json that matches 'connection' property set on 'cosmosDB' in 'CosmosFunction\function.json'. You can run 'func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings ' or specify a connection string in local.settings.json.

But local settings json is presented and copied to output directory. My `.csproj` looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <AzureFunctionsVersion>V4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.10.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.19.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.1.24" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Queues" Version="5.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="4.4.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.13.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.2.0-preview3.23201.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="host.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="local.settings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="appsettings.json">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Any ideas what i can check to make sure that my function reads `local.settings.json` properly?

Answer (score -1):

Locally your Functions settings are present in local.settings.json, But the `local.settings.json` file is not included in the Function Deployment as it is `gitignored`. Thus you need to ***manually add Azure cosmosDB connection string in Azure Functions Configuration/Environment variables*** for the Function to work like below:-

***Local:-***

[image]

**local.settings.json:-**

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "CosmosDbconnection": "AccountEndpoint=https://silicon-cosmosdb.documents.azure.com:443/; AccountKey=xxxxxxxxYACDbM6tQNA==;"
  }
}
```

**Function1.cs:-**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace CosmosDBInproc
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "ToDoList",
            containerName: "Items",
            Connection = "CosmosDbconnection",
            LeaseContainerName = "leases",
            CreateLeaseContainerIfNotExists = true)]IReadOnlyList<ToDoItem> input,
            ILogger log)
        {
            if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
            {
                log.LogInformation("Documents modified " + input.Count);
                log.LogInformation("First document Id " + input[0].id);
            }
        }
    }

    // Customize the model with your own desired properties
    public class ToDoItem
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Function Triggered properly:-**

[image]

***Azure cosmosDb connection string added in Function App:-***

[image]

***Function got deployed and triggered successfully:-***

[image]

An alternative is also to connect your CosmosDb instance in visual Studio like below:-

[image]

Select Next and Choose your CosmosDb account, the connection string will be added and stored as a secret:-

[image]

[image]

**Reference:-**

[Create a function triggered by Azure Cosmos DB | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function)

Comment: Why did u mention deployment when i marked, that `local.settings.json` is `not included` in my local envrionemnt? Look at my `.csproj` file

Comment: @michasaucer You need to have connection string settings present in local.settings.json, In order for your function to run

Comment: Your error code specifies that the CosmosDbConection was not found in the local.settings.json, Thus you are facing that error. If you do not want to have local.settings.json, I have given one Alternative with connected service where you can directly store your connection string as secret.

Comment: Also, this is my csproj file- <None Update="local.settings.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</None>

Comment: I have given the deployment just to show the working of Function in Function app where local.settings.json will not come into play. And you need to add settings in the Function app Environment variables. I have replicated this answer keeping your error in mind.

Comment: Sorry, i didnt mention. I have local.settings.json filled with all of my namespaces, secrets, settings. That project were working for me couple months ago but it started to fail in a way presented in a question

Comment: Can you share your local.settings.json?Cause, The connection string needs to be in this format only-   "CosmosDbconnection": "AccountEndpoint=https://silicon-cosmosdb.documents.azure.com:443/; AccountKey=xxxB7c29fU2lRshOJ6vONKTWXYGE6dpwoX1fU5LzvqSsucHOBW42V1KYACDbM6tQNA==;" Also note- I have kept one space after ;<space>AccountKey

Comment: It is like you mentioned. But its not only CosmosDB connection, it also didnt work for Service bus connection (which has fully qualified namespace suffix) as log as account endpoint suffix for Cosmos DB.

Comment: Like i said, i didnt work with that functions for a months, i also has deployed function on production and it works like a charm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256461/discussion-between-siddheshdesai-and-michasaucer).